# Serverless Log in and registration

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

Im new to using the serverless framework and I need to make a log in page and registration in my React js app. I'm using MongoDB and Serverless as my api. Could someone point me in the right direction how to make this work, since I had no luck finding any examples online.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a serverless fullstack application boilerplate which contains registration and login, using AWS Lambda, AWS HTTP API, Express.js and React.  It does not use MongoDB, however, as that does not pair well w/ AWS Lambda due to connection issues.  Instead it uses a single-table design with AWS DynamoDB to store application data.

https://github.com/serverless-components/fullstack-app